# Regular Expression positive and negative decimal value in objective c

Tags: ios, regex

Could anyone help me for Regular expression for positive and a negative decimal value in objective c.

Answer (score 2):

```
[NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"(?:-|+)?\\d+(\\.\d+)?" options:0 error:NULL]
```

That's what humans consider a decimal. Compilers are different, though.

**Edit:**

```
- (BOOL)checkForSpecialChar:(NSString *) string
{
    static NSRegularExpression *regex = nil;
    if (regex == nil)
        regex = [[NSRegularExpression alloc] initWithPattern:@"(?:-|+)?\\d+(\\.\d+)?" options:0 error:NULL];
    NSRange fullRange = {0, [string length]};
    NSRange range = [regex rangeOfFirstMatchInString:string options:0 range:fullRange];
    return NSEqualRanges(fullRange, range);
}
```

Comment: could you please tell the REGEX value.. Like this sample "^[a-zA-Z0-9_ ]*$"

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand.

Comment: Do you mean you want the naked pattern? It's in the answer, the part between the quotes.

Comment: i'm defining in constants class and using the below code for validating        - (BOOL) checkForSpecialChar:(NSString *) string
{
 NSPredicate *confidenceTest = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES %@", CHARACTER_REGEX];  
 return [confidenceTest evaluateWithObject:string]?YES:NO;
}

Comment: that CHARACTER_REGEX is defined as                                       #define CHARACTER_REGEX  @"[a-zA-Z'-]+"    like this